# CORS ANYWHERE WHITELIST multiple domains using command prompt

Tags: heroku, whitelist

I ma trying to whitelist heroku cors with multiple domains.

1. How to write command using command prompt?  Do I sepearate when using comma or do I repeat CORSANYWHERE_WHITELIST command for each domain?
2. How to white list localhost correctly?

   heroku config:set -a MY_APP_NAME CORSANYWHERE_WHITELIST=https://my-domain.net, https://localhost

Answer (score 0):

So I've been banging my head against a wall with this whitelisting question for days. Finally cracked the code for my situation, at least.
First, yes, separate the domains with commas and no quotes, as: https://siteone.com,http://sitetwo.org,etc.

What was killing me was trying to get my Chrome Extension to work through the whitelist. Turns out that the extension itself presents as a domain to CORS! It looks like:"chrome-extension://kegjjcfijdniznnehjagfpnljpmgafil" so you need to include that in the whitelist. The odd string of characters is your extension ID.

In desperation, I added a lot of logging to the CORS code and discovered this issue. Now everything works like it should!